# What is this web-like organic matter?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I saw this on my window couple of days ago. Does anyone know what it is? I have tried google image search with no luck.

[image: black web]

Comment: Do you have any idea how long that's taken to develop?

Comment: scale would help a lot. I could be looking at an arctic oil spill satellite image.

Comment: Hi @Charles I would say it appeared out of no where I was out in the front lawn and noticed this it would have definitely caught my eye if it was developing and in its early stages

Comment: @John, I cropped the image but this is on my front bay window (outside) it is roughly 2 to 3 inches in length.

Comment: @Irfarino Just out of curiosity, where are you located in the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [slime mold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold) of the genus [Stemonitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemonitis), and I'm thinking the species is [axifera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemonitis_axifera). They tend to form on dead wood, of which seems to be the case in your picture (assuming that we are in fact looking at the wall *just next to* your actual window, since the bottom left of your window can be seen at the top right of the picture).

[image]

Comment: that sounds pretty close, the picture I posted is the outside of the window it is on the aluminum capping and the gray area is the caulking but there is wood underneath the capping just like any other windows. The mold seem to be forming on aluminum in my case. Is this harmful to humans?

Comment: @Irfarino I'm fairly certain it's harmless.